# python - print newline sometimes does not work. Why?

Tags: python-2.7, printing, newline

in python 2.7

```
print("hello\nJoonho")
```

prints

"hello

Joonho"

But

```
a=3
print(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")
```

prints

"(3, "\nhello\nJoonho")

Would you explain why this is happening? "print()" is not a function?
And how to pass by this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` always gives you the printable representation of the object being printed on stdout. When you say `print(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")`, here `(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")` is a tuple and hence represented as tuple object.

To get more clarity on this:
If you do `print(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")[1]` then it actually gets printed as

```
>>> print(0, '\nhello\nJoonho')[1]

hello
Joonho
```

since object denoted by [1] is a string and \n are converted to new line on stdout for string objects.

Comment: Using `[1]` was nice!

Answer (score 1):

Before python 3 print was not a function. In python 3 print is a function.

You can translate python 2.7

```
print(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")
```

to python 3

```
print((a, "\nhello\nJoonho"))
```

So your statement actually prints the representation of the tuple.

That is because when you pass a string to the print function it is printed as it is. If you pass anything else to the print function, for example a tuple its representation is printed. You can also get the representation of an object by using the `repr` function:

```
>>> repr((a, "\nhello\nJoonho"))
"(3, '\\nhello\\nJoonho')"
```

The representation of an object is normally a valid python expression.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, [print is a statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print). So, by calling `print(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")`, you are printing the tuple `(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")`.

You can use the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) function in Python 2 by importing it from the future:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

---

The print statement converts the the object to a string before printing it:

> `print` evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting object to standard output (see below).  If an object is not a string, it is first converted to a string using the rules for string conversions.

So, in `print ("hello\nJoonho")`, the object `("hello\Joonho")` will be converted to a string (`("hello\nJoonho").__str__()`, which results in 'hello\nJoonho'). Then, the string `'hello\nJoonho'` will be printed.

In `print (a, "\nhello\nJoonho")`, `(a, "\nhello\nJoonho")` will be converted to a string (`(a, "\nhello\nJoonho").__str__()`, which results in `"(3, '\\nhello\\nJoonho')"`). Then, the string `"(3, '\\nhello\\nJoonho')"` will be printed. Note that when the second tuple is converted to a string, the `\n` are escaped.

Comment: @JoonhoPark because you are printing string in first statement and tuple in second. Check my example for more clarity

Comment: @JoonhoPark See my answer, the `print` function / statement (depending on the version of python) has two ways of operating. When passed a string it writes it directly to stdout. When passed anything else it writes its *representation* to stdout. The representation of an object is a valid python expression, for example: `repr("\nhello\nJoonho")` is the string `'\nhello\nJoonho'`

Comment: @timakro `repr("\nhello\nJoonho")` evaluates to `"'\\nhello\\nJoonho'"`, which is escaped, so I'm not sure if `print` uses it. In PyPy implementation, they use `str()` to convert to string: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/ed43c2dc0a42843bbf9637b14a2c30dfe2785295/pypy/module/__builtin__/app_io.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#app_io.py-85

I'm not sure with CPython, but empirically it seems that they use something similar to `str()` (we need to check the source code).

Comment: Thank you, FP and others for thoughful explanation. But I need to choose one. I am not expert yet and in my place, MohitC's explanation is so clear. Thank you, guys.